# Segment character of complicate background

Tags: opencv, image-processing

In Optical Character Recognition (OCR), I am facing with the problem of segmenting the characters on the noisy/complicated background image. I have tried one easiest image among 3 (as i think) that I attached here. Also, I have tried the contrast enhancement (Histogram Equalization) since the images are almost low contrast. However, the segmented characters still have poor quality: connected character, unfilled regions and can not work for other images due to the fixed thresholds.

```
    Scalar m = mean(src);
    for ( y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
    {
        for ( x = 0; x < src.cols; x ++ )
        {
            if ( filtered_image.at<uchar>(y,x) > 160 )
            {
                filtered_image.at<uchar>(y, x) = (uchar) m(0);
            }
        }
    }
    GaussianBlur(filtered_image, filtered_image, Size(5, 5), 1, 1, 4);
    imshow("filtered", filtered_image);

    HardThresholding(filtered_image, filtered_image, 70);
    imshow("threshold", filtered_image);
```

1. Remove bright spots by assigning the image average value for those pixels greater than threshold (ex: 180).
2. Gaussian blurring to remove noise.
3. Hard thresholding with respect to fixed threshold value.

If anyone can suggest some ideas, if would be really great.

[image: First image]
[image: Result of First image]

[image: Second image]

[image: Third image]

Comment: Contrast enhancement is useless before binarization. Adjust the threshold instead.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I think contrast enhancement is almost useless before binarization, however, I still encounter several cases that dynamic threshold might be considerable.
![Valid XHTML](http://www.mediafire.com/view/r756prg0vay5qw3/img%20(6).bmp)

![Valid XHTML] ("http://www.mediafire.com/view/z7ip1vqtnfc4532/contrast_thre.png)

Comment: @russel-vk: I am not discussing the benefits of dynamic thresholding in general, I am looking at this particular case, which IMO isn't thresholdable at all (third image).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: oh, I'm sorry. I misunderstood your sentence.

Answer (score 2):

You could try MSER (Maximally stable extremal regions) for blob detection. The VLFeat open source library includes implementation of MSER.

There is entire [scientific competition](http://dag.cvc.uab.es/icdar2013competition/?ch=2&com=results) devoted to text segmentation. Turns out many of the methods utilize MSER as part of their processing pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simple gaussian blur try to use median filter or better some edge preserving filter like Kuwahara.

I also suggest to use more advanced thresholding technique. You could start you research with Otsu thresholding method or hysteresis thresholding maybe.

Answer (score 1):

There are no miracles, there is nothing you can do to get a perfect segmentation, especially in the third case, without a priori information. Even a human couldn't.

For such a difficult case, I would use straight binarization with an automatic threshold. Any kind of filtering, denoising, smoothing, constrast stretching, adaptive thresholding... will at best have no positive effect and at worse finish to erase the characters.

After binarization, find the best arrangement of 3 by 3 boxes of the known size and known spacing.

You can also try to find the inter-character limits (vertical and horizontal) by profile analysis.

If you can afford it, direct template matching with a grid could be a better solution than segmentation.